# knexjs postgresql migration not running properly

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-migration, knex.js

I am building an app use node + express + postgresql + knexjs ORM. I'm trying to run a migration:

`knex migrate:latest`

But my console keeps returning:

`Using environment: development`

`Already up to date`

And this results in my tables not being created.. Here's my migration file:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {

    return Promise.all([

            knex.schema.createTable('address', function(table) {

                table.increments();
                table.string('address_id');
                table.string('addr_1');
                table.string('addr_2');
                table.string('city');
                table.string('state');
                table.string('zip');

        ]);
};


exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {

    return Promise.all([

            knex.schema.dropTable(host_domain + '.address'),

        ]);

};
```

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Note - the tables have NOT been created at the moment I run `knex migrate:latest`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the contents of the `knex_migrations` table?  That's where Knex keeps track of what migrations it has applied.  Is your migration file already in there?

Comment: there's no migration table. there's no table at all

Comment: Sounds like the migrations aren't set up.  Can you post your knexfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knex implement migrations in environment = development by default.
You need run knex migrations by your environment.

For example, you have next knexfile.js:

```
module.exports = {
    myenv: { // it is name of environment
       client: 'pg',
       connection: {
           user: 'me',
           database: 'my_app'
       }
     }
};
```

Command in console:

```
knex migrate:latest --env myenv
```